# Setting up a custom AuthGuard in Angular2 using PHP

Tags: php, angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular2 and currently learning.

This is the folder structure on my project.

```
var/www/html/
        |_(angproject)
                |_(phpscript)
                |       |_login.php
                |_(src)
                   |_(app)
                        |_(admin)
                        |   |_(login)
                        |   |   |_login.component.ts
                        |   |
                        |   |_admin.component.ts
                        |
                        |_(_admin_service)
                        |       |_admin.login.ts
                        |
                        |_(_animations)
                        |
                        |_(front)
                        |
                        |_(_models)
                        |   |_admin.model.ts
                        |
                        |_(_authguard)
                        |   |_adminauth.guard.ts
                        |
                        |_app.adminroute.ts
                        |_app.module.ts
```

This is my **app.adminroute.ts** file:-

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CanActivate } from "@angular/router";

import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './admin/login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './admin/dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { AdminAuthGuard } from './_authguard/adminauth.guard';


export const appAdminRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
          { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
          { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard] }
    ]
  }
];
```

In my **login.component.ts** file, I am storing the **id** of the admin in localstorage:-

```
submitPost()
  {        
      this._adminLogin.postAdminLogin(this.adminLoginmodel).subscribe(
          data => {
                this.responseStatus = data;
                if(this.responseStatus.status == 1)
                {
                  localStorage.setItem('admin_id', this.responseStatus.detail.id);
                  //console.log(localStorage.getItem("admin_id"));
                  this.router.navigate(['admin/dashboard'])
                }
                else
                {
                  alert('Login Error');
                }
              },
          err => {
                console.log(err)
              },
          () => {}
      ); 
      this.status = true;       
  }
```

This is my **adminauth.guard.ts** file:-

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuard {
    http : Http;
    actionUrl : string;
    admin_auth_Url: string;
    adminAuthResponse:Object= []; 


    constructor(public _http: Http) {
       this.http = _http;
       this.admin_auth_Url = 'http://localhost/angproject/phpscript/isadminlogin.php';
    }
    checkAdminAuth() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Accept", "q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9");
        this.actionUrl = this.admin_auth_Url;
        return this.http.post(this.actionUrl, 
                                    {admin_id:localStorage.getItem("admin_id")}, 
                                    { headers: headers })
                                .map(res => res.json()).share();
    }
}
```

The function `checkAdminAuth()` calls for a php file which returns response data in following manner:-

```
{"status":0,"message":"Message comes here","error":}
```

Whenever I will try to visit dashboard page, **checkAdminAuth()** function must hit the php file to check the authentication. If the response status is **0**, it will redirect to `http://localhost:4200/admin`. If status is **1**, it should lead to `http://localhost:4200/admin/dashboard`.

How can I fire the checkAdminAuth function to fetch the response and carry out the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AdminAuthGuard` should implement the `CanActivate` interface. It has a method `canActivate` and it should contain what you have in your `checkAdminAuth`. Otherwise it's never going to be called while routing. Also the `canActivate` should return `Boolean`, `Promise<Boolean>` or `Observable<Boolean>` so you should map your result to return it.

The conditional rerouting you want to achive can be done in the `AdminAuthGuard`like this

```
canActivate() {
    if (/*user is logged in*/) {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
    return false;
}
```